# Tomcat URIEncoding="UTF-8" in eclipse tomcat setting page

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, utf-8, uriencoding

I have eclipse neon which is working correctly with Apache Tomcat 7, and now I want to set URIEncoding="UTF-8" for tomcat's connector. But each time eclipse publishes the project, it will rewrite the server.xml file and deletes my configurations.

I wanted to find a way to set URIEncoding="UTF-8" in eclipse tomcat settings page. There is an option in launch configuration (in tomcat settings page) in common tab as Encoding and I set it to UTF-8, but it is not working too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **{workspace}/Servers** you will find a folder for every Tomcat configuration, containing several configuration files, including the **server.xml**. There you then can **edit the file directly**.

To get changes taken into account **restart Eclipse**.

Comment: Restarting your entire Eclipse IDE is unnecessary. Make the desired edits to the files for your server definition under **{workspace}/Servers** and be sure to save. Then, in the Servers tab, right-click on the corresponding server and choose `Clean...` to re-publish your updated configuration to it. In the case of changing connector configuration, you **will** need to restart the container, but not the entire IDE.

Answer (score 7):

That is the full sentence for encoding case.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"  redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

But yes I think your problem is not related with this sentences because it seen correct. I have the one alternative way to prevent to not overwrite your `server.xml` file when restart. You can edit the same encoding configuration settings inside **Server** `project/folder` in your eclipse workspace.

So when you run again and again, your settings will never overwrite.

Comment: Thank you too, but as @Umais answer was simpler, I marked it as the correct answer. Thanks again

Comment: yes, welcome, I just explain you details and note that his answer is later than me.

Comment: URIEncoding="UTF-8"